# Debug JavaScript in WebStorm

Tags: javascript, debugging, chromium, webstorm

Is it possible to debug JS files from within WebStorm IDE? Preferably, running the app in a Chromium browser instead of using using Chrome developer tools. How do I debug from within WebStorm?

Comment: Did you already check these documents? [1](http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Remote_JavaScript_debugging_with_WebStorm_and_PHPStorm), [2](http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Debugging_a_third-party_site_with_WebStorm_and_PHPStorm), [3](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/debugging-javascript.html).

Comment: Yes to your first question. There are many tools for debugging in Webstorm. "How" you do it is a pretty broad question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. You need to install the "JetBrains IDE Support" add on. Btw: you can run since version 7 Html/JavaScript projects with the builtin webserver.

Answer (score 0):

Since WebStorm 2017.3 you can now use Chrome DevTools and WebStorm debugger at the same time. You no longer need an additional Chrome extension to debug apps in WebStorm.

Read about it in [Debugging JavaScript with WebStorm 2017.3](https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2018/01/debugging-javascript-with-webstorm-2017-3/)